# Subset rows with highest value from multiple columns

Tags: r

I have this kind of issue: I would like to assign a char value to each row based on the highest value within different columns. I'll try to explain better:

```
      col1 col2 col3 col4
row1  10   20   30
row2  20   10   10
row3  30   10   10
```

I would like to assign to `col4` as a factor the name of the column with the highest value within the col1:col3 interval for each row of the Data Frame. For example for `row1` I want in the `col4` the name "col3", for `row2` the name "col1" and so on.

Is there a simple way to do this in R using dplyr or other basic functions?

Comment: `which.max` might work

Comment: what is the expected behavior if there is a tie?

Comment: In case of a tie I would like to chose first column in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't actually even need to use apply. You can simply do an assignment:

```
df$col4 <- names(df)[max.col(df,ties.method="first")]
```

This also takes care of your which column to choose in a tie issue. To show how this works we can modify the original data slightly:

```
df <-read.table(header=T,text="   col1 col2 col3
  10   20   20
  20   10   10
  30   10   10")
```

Note how for the first row col2 and col3 have the same value. Per your comment on using the alphabetically first column in a tie, we would want col2.

Running the above code we see it works as expected:

```
 col1 col2 col3 col4
1   10   20   20 col2
2   20   10   10 col1
3   30   10   10 col1
```

**Edit**: In case you don't only have `cols1 - cols3` in your dataset (there might be other variables you dont want to take the max of) a more complete solution would be to specify the columns you want to take the max of. Something like this:

*Data:*

```
#Note this has an extra id variable on it
df <-read.table(header=T,text="   col1 col2 col3 id
  10   20   20 100
  20   10   10 100
  30   10   10 100")
```

Then you can run the code to see how it works:

```
#The columns we want to take the max of
cols <- c("col1","col2","col3")
df$col4 <- names(df)[names(df) %in% cols][max.col(df[,cols],ties.method="first")]


  col1 col2 col3  id col4
1   10   20   20 100 col2
2   20   10   10 100 col1
3   30   10   10 100 col1
```

Comment: Perfect! This works, just one last question. Is there a way to select only a certain number of columns on which apply this function? If I have 10 columns in total and I want to count which column has the maximum value but only for columns 1:5, how can I write this subset?

Comment: Did you see my edit? You could specify the names of the columns you want that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `which.max` and `names` (or `colnames` if this is a matrix):

```
# Data from example
dat <- data.frame(col1 = c(10, 20, 30), col2 = c(20, 10, 10), col3 = c(30, 10, 10))

dat$col4 <- apply(dat, 1, function(x) names(dat)[which.max(x)])
```